# insert /update data into azure table from on campus database

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I want to maintain the relationship between azure tables and want to insert /update data from on campus database using sql server management studio 2016. It does not give option of chcek/nocheck constraints, as it goes off on number of prefixes?? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to update/insert azure database and maintain relation, only one way,you can use [Transactional replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-geo-replication-overview).

if you want to keep both the databases in sync,you will have rollout some custom solution like below ..

1.write an exe,which can read both tables and compare them .
2.Schedule this as per your frequency from SQlagent in onpremise